# Can iptables be used to convert a single-homed host into a NAT server?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

**Given:** I have a machine (HostA) with **only** one NIC which has Internet connectivity. I have another machine (HostB) with one NIC on the same switch. HostB is *not* configured for Internet access yet. HostA has its default gateway and DNS servers appropriately configured. IPv4 is being used. OSes on the hosts are Ubuntu 13 and Fedora17.

**What I want:** Now, I would like HostB to have Internet connectivity, too. Is this possible using 'some' combination of `iptables`, virtual tun/tap devices, or a VPN setup between HostA and HostB, etc?

**What I already know and can do:** Currently, I can use an `ssh`-based SOCKS proxy on HostB (`ssh -D 9050 UserA@HostA`) and route traffic of select 'socksifiable' applications on HostB via this proxy to HostA and beyond. However, sadly, not all applications are socksifiable. Now, I know very well that if HostA had 2 NICs, I could have used some `iptables` rules to convert HostA into a gateway that would then route traffic between its NIC-1 and NIC-2 (where NIC-1 would be connected to HostB and NIC-2 to Internet). But installing another NIC in HostA is not feasible for me.

PS: I had [posted this earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/596726/can-iptables-be-used-to-convert-a-single-homed-host-into-a-nat-server) on superuser.com but got no useful information.

**edit 1:**

network information

Host A:

```
:> ip addr
[...]
2: p4p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether d4:be:d9:d5:46:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.22.9/24 brd 192.168.22.255 scope global p4p1 

:> ip route
default via 192.168.22.254 dev p4p1 proto static
192.168.22.0/24 dev p4p1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.22.9
```

Host B:

```
:> ip addr
[...]
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 30:f9:ed:d9:2e:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.22.234/24 brd 192.168.22.255 scope global eth0 

:> ip route
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.22.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.22.234 metric 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routing is about "where (and if) to send to". That's not limited to selecting a NIC. In your case routing is very simple though.

You need masquerading in its most simple form (all commands on host A):

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.22.234 -j MASQUERADE
```

And maybe (if not yet) you need allow forwarding:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -s 192.168.22.234 -j ACCEPT
```

Assuming host A is configured as the default gateway for Host B.

**Edit 1:**

After a chat discussion the situation has become clearer. In theory configuring the default gateway on B should have been enough. But it seems that the gateway (which is not under the control of the questioner) blocks host B. Thus the masquerading solution was necessary.

Comment: Thanks, for enlightening this routing-newbie. I will try out your solution soon enough and let you know. Meanwhile, I ran into `tun2socks` that is part of the BadVPN tool. Would greatly appreciate your opinion on this program vs. your solution... as, once again, I'm a routing/networking-newbie.

Comment: @Harry I cannot really comment on this program as I don't know it. But "VPN" sounds like configuration effort and CPU load which you both don't need. VPNs are not used to enable connectivity; they are used to enable security. You asked for connectivity.

Comment: Your solution didn't work. I set up A to be the default gwy on B. Then, I tried the 1st `iptables` command. When it didn't work, I tried the 2nd and 3rd ones also... which didn't work either. What do I do now?

Comment: @Harry Strange. I guess you have to use `tcpdump` on A then to have a look what happens to the packets. Do they arrive at A, do they leave with the source address rewritten to A, do responses arrive from the Internet?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to (quickly) see limited and relevant `tcpdump` traffic on A (I will study tcpdump and iptables man pages later in detail but need the thing working really fast for now)? Also, can I test the above using `ping www.google.com` on B, or should I point my browser on B to www.google.com?

Comment: @Harry Assumed you ping `1.2.3.4` from B and the A interface is `eth0` then you need: `tcpdump -i eth0 -n host 1.2.3.4`

Comment: On A, I issued: `tcpdump -vvvv -i p4p1 -n host 74.125.236.210` (which is www.google.com). When I issue `ping 74.125.236.210` on B, I see no `tcpdump` traffic on A (with all 3 iptables commands you listed above already issued). Does iptables need some kind of saving/restart?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8831/discussion-between-hauke-laging-and-harry)